# Why a newer TOP value in the Atmega328p Timer1 has to be greater than the values in all The compare registers?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, atmega

The datasheet mentioned the following on p.167

> When changing the TOP value the program must ensure that the new TOP value is higher or equal to the
> value of all of the Compare Registers. If the TOP value is lower than any of the Compare Registers, a
> compare match will never occur between the TCNT1 and the OCR1x.

I have no clue what does that mean actually. **Does** that mean that once I defined a top value in OCRnx registers the next one must be greater in value? (Although. this How I got it, I really doubt it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counter will increment until it reaches the TOP value, it will then be cleared and start again.

The value in the compare registers are constantly compared with the current counter value and when they are equal an event occurs (such as set the PWM output or create an interrupt). For that to occur the counter must be able to reach the value stored in the compare register.

Any compare values that are greater than TOP will never be reached.

Comment: ...because when it reaches them the count will start over from zero rather than go any higher.   But that doesn't by itself really enforce much on ordering on changes to the TOP value.  Presumably if it's set lower than the current value that will trigger a reset to zero, though the data sheet should be consulted or an experiment run.

Comment: There's no ordering required - just that the range of counter values encompasses the compare values.

Comment: Yes, but it is at least a curiosity what happens if you set TOP to something lower than the current count.  Not saying you need to answer that, just that it is a legitimate *curiosity* - eg it might reset immediately (if it's a >=) or it might run to rollover and only reset the next time around when an == is satisfied.  Or in theory it might get stuck and never work again until reconfigured...

Comment: @ChrisStratton -  The datasheet states that a compare will never occur in that scenario. In other places in the datasheet, it states that it looks for equality, not >= which is consistent.

Comment: But The statement above says that the new TOP value must be greater than the one stored in any of the compare registers already 
TOP here is not the maximum value the counter can reach it's the value you coded right into the compare registers this doesn't make sense actually

Comment: @ChrisStratton Well according to what I read when you put a value in the compare registers that's already lower than that of the counter. there's two cases one where the compare registers are not double buffered in this case the compare match will be missed and the counter will continue increment to max until it resets. And the other case when the registers are double buffered in this case the compare match will just occur on the next clock cycle directly without waiting for the timer to reset.

Comment: @MahmoudSalah - that is to ensure that equality is reached. It also states in the datasheet in the context of the compare registers that they should not even be written the current value of TCNT because the pipelining of the compare will result in the equality being missed.

Comment: And what does it meant that a compare match will never happen?? shouldn't it just be triggered on the next counter reset??

Comment: *Does* the counter wrap if the match is missed?  Or does it run up to the maximum hardware value and get stuck there?

Comment: @ChrisStratton - as far as I can tell it will wrap around when it reaches FFFF.

Comment: Thanks for filling in those edge-case details!  Those are, I think, the things one would want to know about something like this.